# JS File's `attach` method not always executed when loaded through block template

Tags: 8, javascript

We are using a custom barrio sub theme and have some JS files we attach to our template files using the `{{ attach_library('custom_barrio/my_js_library') }}` line at the top of our twig templates.

Generally, our js files are something like

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
  "use strict";
  
  Drupal.behaviors.coursesBehaviors = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      ... code here....
    }
  }
}
```

If we attach the library in a `page` template, we have no issues, however, when we attach the library in a `block` template the `attach` method doesn't always execute, thus our js never executes.

I've confirmed that the js file exists in the scripts on the browser, it just never gets "attached" by Drupal.

Why does the Drupal attach method not always execute for blocks?

Comment: Show your attach code.

Comment: My attach code is there. The first line of that code is a console log, and it’s not executing. After that’s it’s a bunch of behavior settings like on click events, hovers, etc., and those behaviors aren’t working. If I attach the same file to a page template, it works perfectly fine, just not when attached to a block template.

Comment: By the sounds of it, it should be working. Obviously you are sure that the block is actually rendering on the page? Otherwise I might suggest checking you don't have two Drupal functions with the same names "Drupal.behaviors.coursesBehaviors" - E.g. if you have two JS functions named "Drupal.behaviors.coursesBehaviors" then only one will execute. Otherwise sorry, pretty hard to guess what the issue could be.

Comment: No, I mean show how you are attaching it to the page.

Comment: I've done that as well. It's described in the first sentence: I put `{{ attach_library('custom_barrio/my_js_library') }}` in the template file.